# Spring Boot encoding issue ISO instead of UTF-8

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding

Spring Boot is decoding a String from a `@RequestHeader` annotation with `ISO-8859-1` instead of `UTF-8`.

abstract of application.properties

```
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.http.encoding.force-request=true
spring.http.encoding.force-response=true
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
spring.banner.charset=UTF-8
spring.mandatory-file-encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.freemarker.charset=UTF-8
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/mapping/", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public class MyController {}
```

curl command

```
curl 'https://example.com/mymapping/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Fedora; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: https://example.com/mymapping/' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8' -H 'Cookie: cookiesession1=<*>; mellon-cookie=<*>; JSESSIONID=<*>' --compressed
```

Some special characters are still wrong decoded for example a `ü` will be `Ã¼` afterwards.

With the following workaround I get the correct string.

```
private static final Charset UTF_8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
private static final Charset ISO = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

String textnew = new String(textold.getBytes(ISO), UTF_8);
```

I want to declare my application to decode all data in UTF-8 not ISO or something similiar. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would be good if you provided at least a minimum controller and a sample request that doesn't work. You can "copy as cURL" in Chrome.

Comment: But besides that point, there is no specification for request header encoding, I would expect them to support ISO-8859-1 at most, so what you're doing is probably ok, unless the client can send you an additional parameter specifying what the encoding is.

Comment: I searched already how to set the header encoding but I didnt find any solution for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere i read Java expects that *.properties files are encoded in ISO-8859-1 and that's why Spring treats application.properties as if it's in ISO-8859-1.Try using YAML instead of properties files.

Comment: You are right, in Eclipse the whole project is configured as UTF-8 and the application.properties file is ISO-8859-1. I changed that but no difference. I will dig a bit deeper to find maybe the problem there.

Comment: Try to add PropertySource annotation with encoding parameter into your Configuaration file:

**@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application-${env}.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")**

Comment: Added this line to my application. Sadly the same

Comment: you are adding the value as :value = "classpath:application.properties"

Comment: yes, @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", encoding = "UTF-8") the only difference i have no configuration class. I have all my config in application.properties and also the same file in the folder where it will be executed to override some settings, I added it to my controller class at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Can you please verify the response headers what is the value for  Content-Type:?
 for ex :application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: Here I see that the Content-Type is wrong but why?
Content-Type => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1